# Bootstrap-formhelpers select box

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-form-helper

I've got a webpage with bootstrap selectbox.

When i use

```
<div class = "bfh-selectbox">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "selectbox1" value = "">
    <a class = "bfh-selectbox-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="bfh-selectbox" >
    <span class = "bfh-selectbox-option input-medium" data-option="1">Option 1</span>  
    <b class = "caret"></b>
    </a>
    <div class = "bfh-selectbox-options">
        <input type="text" class="bfh-selectbox-filter">
        <div role="listbox">
            <ul role="option">
                <li class = "reg-select"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="1">Option 1</a></li>
                <li class = "reg-select"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="2">Option 2</a></li>
                <li class = "reg-select"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="3">Option 3</a></li>
                <li class = "reg-select"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="4">Option 4</a></li>
                <li class = "reg-select"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="5">Option 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

every javascript code on the page stops working.

Besides that, the selectbox cannot be toggled somehow. I added every css and js files from bootstrap and bootstrap-formhelpers site.

My javascript code to toggle the selectbox:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.reg-select').click(function() {

                    $().bfhselectbox('toggle');

            });
    });

</script>
```

Anyone else who has had any trouble with this?

Comment: You have a div I don't see a selectbox ? How about you make a fiddle or something ?

Comment: Added the complete html code. The 'bfh-selectbox' div class kept my javascript from working, so i figured id only post that part.

Comment: Well you could have mentioned that you're using bootstrap form helper extensions (not just standard bootstrap), anyway, here is a fiddle with your code, it seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/DcB9T/

Comment: I see that it's working. I don't get why it doesn't on my page.

Comment: Well make sure you have the css and javascript files loaded in the correct order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you probably have your resources loaded in the wrong order. Make sure they go like this:

**CSS**:

- bootstrap.css
- bootstrap-formhelpers.css
- yourapp.css

**JS**:

- jquery.js
- bootstrap.js
- bootstrap-formhelpers.js
- yourapp.js

Comment: I deleted some ajax.googleapis.com jquery source. Then I put all the css and js in the correct order. Thx a lot!

Comment: how to set selected value from script